# Args vs ArgTypes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

I'm trying to better understand when to use `args` vs when to use `argTypes`? What are the differences?

From what I read it seems that argTypes is just an expansion of args and allows for better functionality an documentations. But is there more?

In the case below, we have can update the 'label' within the storybook UI whether its `argTypes` or `args`.

** Adding Minimal Reproducible Example **

```
// Button.stories.js

export default {
  title: 'Button',
  argTypes: {
    label: { control: 'text' },
  },
};

export const Basic = (args) => <Button {...args} />;
Basic.args = {
  label: '',
};
```

Comment: May you add a [mcve] showing what you're talking about?

Comment: @evolutionxbox added an example. thanks!

Comment: `args` is actually the arguments being passed to the component. `argTypes` looks like some kind of descriptive type object.

Comment: They are totally different. What makes you think same?

Comment: thanks @BhojendraRauniyar can you explain how they are different and what each would be used for?

Comment: https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/api/argtypes explains `argTypes`, and https://storybook.js.org/docs/react/writing-stories/args explains `args`

Answer (score 5):

Reposting a helpful explanation from the discord chat:

> arg is the value passed to the Story. They're analogous to props, in React. argType is the type (label, description, type, control, defaultValue, etc.) for an arg. They're analogous to propType in React, or a component interface property, in TypeScript.